# How to import all tsv folders while retaining file name as the names in the list

Tags: r

I know this might seem like a question that I could research, but that is not the case.

I want to import all files ending in .tsv in a particular directory. To do this, I ran:

```
setwd("directory")
dfs = list.files(pattern = "*.tsv")
raw <- lapply(dfs, read.table, sep = "\t")
```

However, when I do names(raw), I get NULL.

If I were to do

```
names(raw) <- dfs
```

Then the actual names and the names I assigned do not line up.
How can I make sure the file name is kept as the data frame name when putting it into a list?

Thanks

Comment: `names(raw)` should be `NULL` on account of how `lapply` works on your unnamed vector `dfs`. Can you provide the output of `str(dfs)` and `str(raw)`?

Comment: what about putting the `names(raw) <- dfs` before the `lapply` statement? That way you assign the names beforehand.

Comment: @shuckle That won't work. `raw` only gets defined in the `lapply` statement.

Comment: sorry, I think I meant `names(dfs) <- dfs`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use when I want to do the same thing. Its a cow but its worked well for me. I just pulled it out of a much longer script so hopefully it works for you.

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}
filenames=list.files(path=yourpath, full.names=TRUE)
filenameshort<-list.files(path=yourpath, full.names=FALSE)
endnames=NULL
for(i in 1:length(filenames)){endnames[i]=substrRight(filenames[[i]],3)}
filenames=filenames[ifelse(endnames=="tsv",TRUE,FALSE)]
filenameshort=filenameshort[ifelse(endnames=="tsv",TRUE,FALSE)]
numberfiles=length(filenames)
for(i in 1:numberfiles){assign(filenameshort[i],read.table(filenames[i]))}
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the final data frames are not added to a list. How can they be added to a list with the data frame names maintained?

Comment: Try adding `lists=list();for(i in 1:numberfiles){lists<-c(lists, filenameshort[i])}`